# Can I install Lineage OS on unsupported device?

Tags: htc-desire, lineageos

I don't know what to do, because I have older phone `HTC Desire 526G` and updates are just not pushed and I believe that they will not push them ever, but out there there is so many vulnerabilities for the OS which I'm running currently `4.4.2` Kitkat.

Buying a new phone is not an option for me right now. So my question here is; can I somehow install Lineage OS on that device? What is the worst it can happen?